# how to set focus on fullpage.js slide/section again

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, fullpage.js

I am currently having a problem with fullpage.js scrolling after opening an overlay div and closing it again. (via jQuery, fadeIn and fadeOut)

The overlay div's code is outside of the

```
<div id="fullpage">...</div>
```

-stuff. How can I set the focus on the fullpage content again, so I don't have to click/touch on e.g. its background again, to "reactivate" its scrolling ability?

Comment: Can you provide a reproduction of your problem in jsfiddle or codepen? Why your overlay is outside fullpage.js anyway?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, but the layout is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lajc3wpe/
The only thing is, that it works.. my problem is, when I click on the close button x, then I have to click on the background or any other element of the page, before I can use the scrolling again.
I will still try to make the problem work ;)

Comment: Without a reproduction its not easy to help.